# Are there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $x^2 +ny^2$ represents infinitely many primes?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

The question is

> Are there infinitely many integers $n$ such that $x^2 + ny^2$ represents infinitely many primes?

It is known that (Introductory Algebraic Number Theory by S.Alaca and K.Williams)

> If  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is a principal ideal domain for some squarefree integer $d$ and $q$ be an odd prime such that $$(d\mid q) =1 $$ Then there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $$q = \mid u^2 - dv^2 \mid $$

Here $(.|.)$ is Legendre's symbol.

I think there is a conjecture that there are infinitely many squarefree positive integers $d$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is a PID. If this conjecture is true then there will be infinitely many integers $n$ such that $x^2 + ny^2$ represents infinitely many primes using the above theorem.

Is there a simple criterion other than the above conjecture which I am not seeing? It is sufficient even if you provide the references.

Comment: How did you get from $|u^2-nv^2|$ to $x^2+ny^2$? Won't you want to work with $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt n]$ for that?

Comment: I understand that there is confusion in the notation, I am actually considering all integers $n$ in the question

Comment: Let $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ be a square-free integer. There exist infinitely many primes $p$ with $p=x^2+ny^2$ if and only if there exist infinitely many primes $p$ which split as a product of principal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$. By Kummer-Dedekind, a prime $p\neq 2$ splits iff $-n$ is a non-zero quadratic residue mod $p$. With quadratic reciprocity, it's easy to show there exist infinitely many such primes. The problem is that the primes above $(p)$ must be principal too. PIDs are a special case because they have class number $1$.

Comment: Probably an answer in http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf

Comment: Every primitive binary quadratic form represents infinitely many primes. This is due to Dirichlet.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer If it answers the question please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A theorem due to Dirichlet (completely proved only later, for example by Weber [here](https://eudml.org/doc/157037)) states that every primitive binary quadratic form represents infinitely many primes. The proof is much simpler than the theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions and uses the fact that $(s-1) \zeta_K(s)$ has a nonzero limit as $s \to 1$.

The result can also be deduced from the known fact that each ideal class contains infinitely many prime ideals.